# Solving an Improper Multiple Integral

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

I have an improper multiple integral that looks like this

$\int_{x} f(x) \int_{y} g(y) dy dx$

I have tried to solve the internal one ($g(y)$) and I reached to this equation

$\int_{x}f(x)\left[constant + constant\int_{y}g(y)dy\right]dx$

I am not sure how to continue solving this integral. Is it possible to write it as

$\int_{x}f(x)*(constant) dx + constant \int_{x}f(x)\int_{y}g(y)dydx$

I appreciate a hint to a method or theory that helps me solve this.

Comment: What prevent you to split to product of integrals?

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible (the second expression)